# How an unprivileged user could kill a process she didn't start?

Tags: linux, process, database, kill, signal

I stumbled upon something very surprising which I cannot understand on a Red Hat EL 5.6 box : the user **hri** (which is in the group **dba**) is able to kill processes owned by user **oracle** (which is also in group **dba**).

Is anybody able to explain what could allow an unprivileged user to kill another user's processes? Even if Oracle process was written to handle signals, I though processes could not trap SIGKILL(9).

Below is a session log which shows that.

```
OracleServer:/home/hri> export ORACLE_SID=HRIXXXDW

OracleServer:/home/hri> sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.5.0 - Production on Thu Dec 12 17:30:56 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All Rights Reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> startup
ORA-09925: Unable to create audit trail file
Linux-x86_64 Error: 13: Permission denied
Additional information: 9925
SQL> Disconnected

OracleServer:/home/hri> ps auxf | grep HRIXXX
hri      28295  0.0  0.0  61164   676 pts/9    S+   17:31   0:00                  \_ grep HRIXXX
oracle   28263  0.0  0.0 759668 17384 ?        Ss   17:31   0:00 ora_pmon_HRIXXXDW
oracle   28265  0.0  0.0 758488 16576 ?        Ss   17:31   0:00 ora_psp0_HRIXXXDW
oracle   28267  0.1  0.0 758488 23948 ?        Ss   17:31   0:00 ora_mman_HRIXXXDW
oracle   28269  0.0  0.0 760968 19308 ?        Ss   17:31   0:00 ora_dbw0_HRIXXXDW
oracle   28271  0.0  0.0 760960 19284 ?        Ss   17:31   0:00 ora_dbw1_HRIXXXDW
oracle   28273  0.0  0.0 758488 16656 ?        Ss   17:31   0:00 ora_lgwr_HRIXXXDW
oracle   28275  0.0  0.0 758492 19092 ?        Ss   17:31   0:00 ora_ckpt_HRIXXXDW
oracle   28277  0.0  0.0 758488 16596 ?        Ss   17:31   0:00 ora_smon_HRIXXXDW
oracle   28279  0.0  0.0 758488 16588 ?        Ss   17:31   0:00 ora_reco_HRIXXXDW
oracle   28281  0.0  0.0 758488 16772 ?        Ss   17:31   0:00 ora_mmon_HRIXXXDW
oracle   28283  0.0  0.0 758488 16612 ?        Ss   17:31   0:00 ora_mmnl_HRIXXXDW

OracleServer:/home/hri> /bin/kill -9 28263

OracleServer:/home/hri> ps auxf | grep HRIXXX
hri      28309  0.0  0.0  61164   676 pts/9    S+   17:31   0:00                  \_ grep HRIXXX
oracle   28265  0.0  0.0 758488 16584 ?        Ss   17:31   0:00 ora_psp0_HRIXXXDW
oracle   28267  0.0  0.0 758488 23948 ?        Ss   17:31   0:00 ora_mman_HRIXXXDW
oracle   28269  0.0  0.0 760968 19316 ?        Ss   17:31   0:00 ora_dbw0_HRIXXXDW
oracle   28271  0.0  0.0 760960 19284 ?        Ss   17:31   0:00 ora_dbw1_HRIXXXDW
oracle   28273  0.0  0.0 758488 16656 ?        Ss   17:31   0:00 ora_lgwr_HRIXXXDW
oracle   28275  0.0  0.0 758492 19096 ?        Ss   17:31   0:00 ora_ckpt_HRIXXXDW
oracle   28277  0.0  0.0 758488 16596 ?        Ss   17:31   0:00 ora_smon_HRIXXXDW
oracle   28279  0.0  0.0 758488 16588 ?        Ss   17:31   0:00 ora_reco_HRIXXXDW
oracle   28281  0.0  0.0 758488 16772 ?        Ss   17:31   0:00 ora_mmon_HRIXXXDW
oracle   28283  0.0  0.0 758488 16620 ?        Ss   17:31   0:00 ora_mmnl_HRIXXXDW

OracleServer:/home/hri> ps auxf | grep HRIXXX
hri      28435  0.0  0.0  61164   676 pts/9    S+   17:32   0:00                  \_ grep HRIXXX
```

Below are a `kill -15` then a `kill -9`, with strace :

```
OracleServer:/home/hri> ps auxf | grep HRIXXX
hri      26278  0.0  0.0  61164   676 pts/9    S+   17:16   0:00                  \_ grep HRIXXX
oracle   12412  0.0  0.0 759660 19724 ?        Ss   16:10   0:00 ora_pmon_HRIXXXDW
oracle   12414  0.0  0.0 758484 16608 ?        Ss   16:10   0:00 ora_psp0_HRIXXXDW
oracle   12416  0.0  0.0 758484 23992 ?        Ss   16:10   0:00 ora_mman_HRIXXXDW
oracle   12418  0.0  0.0 760980 19352 ?        Ss   16:10   0:00 ora_dbw0_HRIXXXDW
oracle   12420  0.0  0.0 760968 19316 ?        Ss   16:10   0:00 ora_dbw1_HRIXXXDW
oracle   12422  0.0  0.0 758484 16700 ?        Ss   16:10   0:00 ora_lgwr_HRIXXXDW
oracle   12424  0.0  0.0 758504 19152 ?        Ss   16:10   0:00 ora_ckpt_HRIXXXDW
oracle   12426  0.0  0.0 758484 16708 ?        Ss   16:10   0:00 ora_smon_HRIXXXDW
oracle   12428  0.0  0.0 758484 16616 ?        Ss   16:10   0:00 ora_reco_HRIXXXDW
oracle   12430  0.0  0.0 758484 16812 ?        Ss   16:10   0:00 ora_mmon_HRIXXXDW
oracle   12432  0.0  0.0 758484 16644 ?        Ss   16:10   0:00 ora_mmnl_HRIXXXDW

OracleServer:/home/hri> strace kill 12414
execve("/bin/kill", ["kill", "12414"], [/* 32 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xe36e000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b25c7756000
uname({sys="Linux", node="
OracleServer", ...})  = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=101954, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 101954, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x2b25c7757000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)      = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220\332\301\302;\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1722304, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b25c7770000
mmap(0x3bc2c00000, 3502424, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3bc2c00000
mprotect(0x3bc2d4e000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3bc2f4e000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x14e000) = 0x3bc2f4e000
mmap(0x3bc2f53000, 16728, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x3bc2f53000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b25c7771000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x2b25c7771260) = 0
mprotect(0x3bc2f4e000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3bc2a1b000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x2b25c7757000, 101954)          = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xe36e000
brk(0xe38f000)                          = 0xe38f000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=56450560, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 56450560, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x2b25c7772000
close(3)                                = 0
kill(12414, SIGTERM)                    = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?

OracleServer:/home/hri> ps auxf | grep HRIXXX
hri      26328  0.0  0.0  61164   676 pts/9    S+   17:16   0:00                  \_ grep HRIXXX
oracle   12412  0.0  0.0 759660 19724 ?        Ss   16:10   0:00 ora_pmon_HRIXXXDW
oracle   12414  0.0  0.0 758484 16608 ?        Ss   16:10   0:00 ora_psp0_HRIXXXDW
oracle   12416  0.0  0.0 758484 23992 ?        Ss   16:10   0:00 ora_mman_HRIXXXDW
oracle   12418  0.0  0.0 760980 19352 ?        Ss   16:10   0:00 ora_dbw0_HRIXXXDW
oracle   12420  0.0  0.0 760968 19316 ?        Ss   16:10   0:00 ora_dbw1_HRIXXXDW
oracle   12422  0.0  0.0 758484 16700 ?        Ss   16:10   0:00 ora_lgwr_HRIXXXDW
oracle   12424  0.0  0.0 758504 19152 ?        Ss   16:10   0:00 ora_ckpt_HRIXXXDW
oracle   12426  0.0  0.0 758484 16708 ?        Ss   16:10   0:00 ora_smon_HRIXXXDW
oracle   12428  0.0  0.0 758484 16616 ?        Ss   16:10   0:00 ora_reco_HRIXXXDW
oracle   12430  0.0  0.0 758484 16812 ?        Ss   16:10   0:00 ora_mmon_HRIXXXDW
oracle   12432  0.0  0.0 758484 16644 ?        Ss   16:10   0:00 ora_mmnl_HRIXXXDW

OracleServer:/home/hri> strace kill -9 12414
execve("/bin/kill", ["kill", "-9", "12414"], [/* 32 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x1b155000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2ac77c2e4000
uname({sys="Linux", node="
OracleServer", ...})  = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=101954, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 101954, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x2ac77c2e5000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)      = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220\332\301\302;\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1722304, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2ac77c2fe000
mmap(0x3bc2c00000, 3502424, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3bc2c00000
mprotect(0x3bc2d4e000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3bc2f4e000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x14e000) = 0x3bc2f4e000
mmap(0x3bc2f53000, 16728, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x3bc2f53000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2ac77c2ff000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x2ac77c2ff260) = 0
mprotect(0x3bc2f4e000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3bc2a1b000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x2ac77c2e5000, 101954)          = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x1b155000
brk(0x1b176000)                         = 0x1b176000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=56450560, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 56450560, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x2ac77c300000
close(3)                                = 0
kill(12414, SIGKILL)                    = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?

OracleServer:/home/hri> ps auxf | grep HRIXXX
hri      26380  0.0  0.0  61164   676 pts/9    S+   17:17   0:00                  \_ grep HRIXXX
```

Now some information on the users and the OS:

```
OracleServer:/home/hri> uname -a
Linux OracleServer 2.6.18-186.el5 #1 SMP Wed Jan 27 18:11:22 EST 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

OracleServer:/home/hri> cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.6 (Tikanga)

OracleServer:/home/hri> id
uid=20314(hri) gid=20175(hri) groups=20001(dba),20175(hri)

OracleServer:/home/hri> id oracle
uid=20001(oracle) gid=20001(dba) groups=20001(dba),20000(xxxxx),20768(xxxxx),20329(xxxxx),20767(xxxxx),20930(xxxxx),20271(xxxxx),20316(xxxxx)

OracleServer:/home/hri> alias kill
bash: alias: kill: not found

OracleServer:/home/hri> type kill
kill is a shell builtin

OracleServer:/home/hri> which kill
/bin/kill

OracleServer:/home/hri> l /bin/kill
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14864 Sep 22  2010 /bin/kill

OracleServer:/home/hri> file /bin/kill
/bin/kill: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, stripped
```

**Edit**, thanks to **jjlin** comment:

It is **hri** user who started the $ORACLE_SID (this is what is shown on the first session log posted).

Permissions on `oracle` binary shown a *suid* and *sgid* set.

```
OracleServer:/home/hri> l /oracle/product/10.2.0.5/bin/oracle
-rwsr-s--x 1 oracle dba 116208733 Jul  1 09:29 /oracle/product/10.2.0.5/bin/oracle
```

And indeed, the `/proc/*/status`'s `Uid` line shows that *Real UID* is `20314` (which is the user id of **hri**) while *Effective UID* is `20001` (which is **oracle**).

```
OracleServer:/home/hri> ps auxf | grep HRIXXX | grep 9609
oracle    9609  0.0  0.0 759668 19692 ?        Ss   08:41   0:00 ora_pmon_HRIXXXDW

OracleServer:/home/hri> grep [UG]id: /proc/9609/status
Uid:    20314   20001   20001   20001
Gid:    20175   20001   20001   20001
```

So it must be that: Oracle does run its [System ID (SID)](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORACLE_SID) sub-processes as *Real UID* of database owner, while the *Effective UID* is Oracle's.

Thank you!

References:

- Real UID vs. Effective UID: http://unixpapa.com/incnote/setuid.html
- /proc/[pid]/status description: http://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/5/proc/
- Oracle SID: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORACLE_SID

Comment: What are the permissions on your `oracle` executable, and did user `hri` start your Oracle instance?

Comment: @MathieuMD Since you seem to have figured this out, posting your own answer would be a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle runs its SID sub-processes as *Real UID* of database owner (**hri** here), while the *Effective UID* is Oracle's (**oracle**). Which is why **hri** was able to kill what was actually its own processes.

You can use `ps axf -O ruid,ruser,euid,euser` to display side-by-side both RUID and EUID.